# Converting data type in R

Tags: r

I have problem with converting data type from character to factor.
I have tried the following code:

```
#data$xx=as.factor(data$xx), 
#as.character(as.factor(xx)),
#data[sapply(data, is.character)] <- lapply(data[sapply(data, is.character)], as.factor)
#library(dplyr)- data <- data %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.factor)
```

But, when I check with `#is.factor(xx)` or use `independent_test` in "coin" package it said = false and error not support "character"
What should I do? Or I have done something wrong?

Comment: You did all these transformations? What are you really trying to do. It's easier to help if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output data.

Comment: `data$xx` ≠ `xx`. Is this your problem?